# Theory - Java - Abstract data type and reference data type

Tags: java, reference, abstract, language-lawyer, primitive

Do the concepts of "Abstract data type" and "Reference data type" refer to the same thing and, thus, used in contraposition of "Primitive data type"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Traditionally, the "[Abstract Data Type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_data_type)" (see also [this definition](http://xlinux.nist.gov/dads//HTML/abstractDataType.html)) is used to designate the abstract concept of a "class". Wikipedia says:

> Abstract data types are purely theoretical entities, used (among other
>   things) to simplify the description of abstract algorithms, to
>   classify and evaluate data structures, and to formally describe the
>   type systems of programming languages. However, an ADT may be
>   implemented by specific data types or data structures, in many ways
>   and in many programming languages; or described in a formal
>   specification language. ADTs are often implemented as modules: the
>   module's interface declares procedures that correspond to the ADT
>   operations, sometimes with comments that describe the constraints.
>   This information hiding strategy allows the implementation of the
>   module to be changed without disturbing the client programs.

In particular, a numeric data type, whether primitive type or reference type, *are* instances of "abstract data types".

The [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/) uses the words "Primitive Data Type/Values" and "Reference Data Types/Values" in chapter 4.1:

> 4.1 The Kinds of Types and Values
>
> There are two kinds of types in the Java programming language:
>   primitive types (§4.2) and reference types (§4.3). There are,
>   correspondingly, two kinds of data values that can be stored in
>   variables, passed as arguments, returned by methods, and operated on:
>   primitive values (§4.2) and reference values (§4.3).

However, the "abstract data type" wording is never used, with good reason.

Answer (score 0):

In java it does, in my opinion.
The simple explaination is, that you can't use any data type except for primitives or classes and classes are reference datatypes.